# Disqus comment counter multilingual

Tags: php, javascript, comments, disqus

I have a Disqus plugin on a multilingual Joomla 3.1 website. Everything works fine. I managed to make it multilingual, to find out website language and change Disqus language with website language change.

The thing is that I have a counter to show the comments count on the top of my website that links to the bottom where the comments are (and the designer of the website wants this counter show both the number and the phraze (for example: 11 comments)), and I cannot make that multilingual. It always shows me the language I set on my Disqus account. I tried php, js, nothing helps. Has anyone else met this problem? What solution could you offer?

Answer (score 0):

The comment counter currently can't be presented in different languages, it only substitutes the string that you set in your Disqus admin settings.

If you aren't completely stuck on including the phrase, we generally recommend using just the number for multilingual websites. You can also build your own comment counter with the API using this guide: http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/1131783

If you do this, we'd recommend caching the results on your own server or else the 1000 requests/hour will run out quickly on a busy site.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can change language, check it [here](https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/466249-multi-lingual-websites).
Pay attention to **"Best Practices"** section